# Универсальный ListBox.ItemTemplate. Привязка ItemTemplate к DisplayMemberPath

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу custom control, в шаблоне содержащий ListBox с переопределенным шаблонов ItemTemplate. Тип объектов коллекции заранее не известен. Как привязать ItemTemplate, чтобы он отображал поле класса указанное в DisplayMemberPath?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding SelectedItems}" 
         DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Label Content="{Binding /*какое выражение?*/}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: Обычно `DisplayMemberPath` не используется, если есть `ItemTemplate`, т. к. они конфликтуют. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7486992/276994 Расскажите лучше, какая перед вами реальная задача.

Comment: Задача написать контрол на базе `XamComboEditor` (Infragistics). У контрола, в режиме `AllowMultipleSelection="True"`, должна быть панель, отображающая коллекцию выделенных элементов в виде лэйблов-ярлычков с крестиком. При нажатии на крестик, выделение элемента должно сниматься. Для реализации взял `ListBox`, переопределил шаблон `ItemsPanelTemplate`. Заменил стандартную на `WrapPanel`. Так же переопределил `ItemTemplate` - вставил `StackPanel` с `Label` и `Button`. Так как тип элементов коллекции не известен, не могу привязать `Label.Content` для корректного отображения нужной информации.

Comment: VladD, рассказал выше.

Answer (score 1):

Сообразил! Это было не так-то просто.

Итак, идея: мы создаём контрол, который будет своему child-элементу устанавливать нужный `DataContext`. Делаем так. Для начала создаём custom control:

```
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.Ignore, Readability = Readability.Unreadable)]
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class DisplayMemberPathPropagator : Control
{
    static DisplayMemberPathPropagator()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(DisplayMemberPathPropagator),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DisplayMemberPathPropagator)));
    }

    #region dp string DisplayMemberPath, on change SetBinding for InnerDataContext
    public string DisplayMemberPath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(DisplayMemberPathPropagator),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, (o, args) =>
                {
                    var self = (DisplayMemberPathPropagator)o;
                    self.SetBinding(InnerDataContextProperty, (string)args.NewValue);
                }));
    #endregion

    #region dp object InnerDataContext
    public object InnerDataContext
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(InnerDataContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InnerDataContextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerDataContextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "InnerDataContext", typeof(object), typeof(DisplayMemberPathPropagator));
    #endregion

    #region dp UIElement Content
    public UIElement Content
    {
        get { return (UIElement)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Content", typeof(UIElement), typeof(DisplayMemberPathPropagator));
    #endregion
}
```

и определяем стиль для него в Themes\Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DisplayMemberPathPropagator}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DisplayMemberPathPropagator}">
                <ContentControl Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                DataContext="{TemplateBinding InnerDataContext}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Теперь его можно использовать:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding SelectedItems}" 
         Tag="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <local:DisplayMemberPathPropagator DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Tag,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}">
               <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
           </local:DisplayMemberPathPropagator>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Пробуйте!